# select rows based on todays date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select records from a database only if they match today's date. The format for the date in the database is `2012-06-20 9:30:00` I am using the statement `SELECT id FROM`newsreports`WHERE DATE(newsdate) = CURDATE()` but it doesn't not return any records for today?

Screenshot of column with dates

http://img135.imageshack.us/img135/8399/2347f03df0394cd898c7fc5.png

Comment: It looks good to me. Are you sure there're news present for current date?

Comment: What is the column type? Text or DateTime?

Comment: You may want to ignore the time portion from `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') = FORMAT_DATE(NOW(newsdate), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or better:

```
DATE(newsdate) = DATE(NOW())
```

The best way is to store the additional column with **2001-09-11** date format and compare this one

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98c94/1), thanks to @Conrad Frix

Comment: i tried both solutions and also removed the time portion from the column so it only has the date y-m-d but still does not work

Comment: @Mr.1.0 worked [fine here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98c94/1). odiszapc feel free to include the demo in your answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the curdate function is going to give you something different than the date format you've got in the database.

Take a look at the docs here

[MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

It's supposed to return a date in this format:

```
2008-11-11
```

So, you could either search for a date range between curdate() and curdate() + INTERVAL 1 DAY (untested), or store the dates in the curdate() format.